# How to get the SharePoint list item from multiple site collections using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Can anyone tell me how to get the SharePoint list item using JavaScript?

I have two site collections: site1 and site2. I am working in site1 application and I want to get the list items of site2. How can I achieve this? Please help me.

This is the code I am using on JavaScript side:

```
var ctx;   
var listItem;
var title;
var col1;
var col2;

function SetItemValue(listItemId, listId, siteUrl, webUrl) {
    ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web;
    var site = ctx.get_site(siteUrl);//Here passing the second sitecollection url     
    if (webUrl != undefined && webUrl != '')
        web = site.openWeb(webUrl);
    else
        web = site.openWeb('');
    var list = web.get_lists().getById(listId);//Here passing the valid guid of list id
    listItem = list.getItemById(listItemId);
    ctx.load(list);
    ctx.load(listItem);
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(OnListLoaded);

    list.update();
    web.update();
    ctx.load(web);
}

function OnListLoaded() {
    listItem.set_item(col1, 'Hi');
    listItem.set_item(col2, 'Test');
    listItem.update();

    ctx.load(listItem);
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(OnListUpdated, OnError);
}

function OnListUpdated(args) {
}

function OnError(sender, args) {
    alert(args.get_message());
}
```

It shows a message like "List does not exist". I think it will check the list from first site collection, which is why this message will popup. Can anyone help me to resolve this please?

Thanks,

Rasu

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "constructor" `new ClientContext(serverAbsoluteUrl)` to create a context for a specific URL:

```
function SetItemValue(listItemId, listId, siteUrl, webUrl) {
    ctx = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var web;
    var site = ctx.get_site(siteUrl);//Here passing the second sitecollection url     
    if (webUrl != undefined && webUrl != '')
        web = site.openWeb(webUrl);

    // ...
```

Comment: Is it not a cross domain call? I think It is not possible with JSOM, SharePoint App modal has to be used here. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/officeapps/archive/2012/11/29/solving-cross-domain-problems-in-apps-for-sharepoint.aspx